# ui grid header menu option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I would like to hide one of the header menus option from ui-grid, I don't want to display "Hide Column" option in enableFiltering

```
 enableFiltering: true,
 enableColumnMenus:false
```

enableColumnMenus:false is hiding entire menu from header which doesn't suits with my requirement, I can achieve this with css by display none option for it, but I would like to do it from javascript end,can someone please help me on this[image: UI-GRID]

Answer (score 1):

You can use enableHiding as false in your columnDefs. For example:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'gender', enableHiding: false, suppressRemoveSort: true, 
                     sort:  {direction: uiGridConstants.ASC }}]
```

For more details check this link [Customizing Column Menu - UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu)

I don't think you can give this at grid level. i.e in $scope.gridOptions

Comment: ~vikash, Thanks for update enableHiding option working on load but when we click on sort options in the menu remove sort is coming extra and I don t want to use this in columnDefs

Comment: Hope using suppressRemoveSort:true solves your issue. I will update my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can make it columnDefs not gridOptions level we need to use   suppressRemoveSort along with enableHiding

```
  enableHiding: false,
  suppressRemoveSort: true
```